# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) while loading pictures from mongodb in heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

Im having an issue with my app. It doesnt load images from my database, sometimes it loads for a couple of hours then they disappear from the app. Has anyone solved this error?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCcba.png)

Comment: Storing images in a database isn't a good idea, but anyway. Your question doesn't have enough data to help you. How do you load the images? How are they stored?

Answer (score 0):

@Konrad Linkowski is correct, Storing images in a database isn't a good idea,
so you can store the image  by using that image id , like that you no  need to store image in db ,